# SQL Oracle - where clause on value on column next to condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which return more than a million rows based on the `Entity-Attribute-Value` model. Note that each entity may have a different number of attributes, therefore, I can't just look for a row ID. Here is an example table:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| EntityID | Attr_Name | Attr_Value |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 1        | Age       | 2          |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 1        | Class     | Spatial    |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 2        | Age       | 3          |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 2        | Class     | Industrial |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 3        | Class     | Industrial |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

I need to filter all the `EntityID` according to their `Class`. In this example, let's say I need all the `EntityID` that are `Industrial`, I want my query to return rows `3-4-5` (so all rows associated with `EntityID` `2` and `3`).

I thought about using a sub-select on the same query and grouping by `EntityID` and looking only for all `EntityIDs` that are `Industrial` in the where clause (`WHERE EntityID = (subquery)`), but is not effective at all. The query has a lot of joins and unions and therefore, it takes a lot of time. I'm open to all suggestions for a more efficient way of doing it (which I'm sure there is) !

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.entityid = t.entityid and
                    t2.attr_name = 'Class' and
                    t2.attr_value = 'Industrial'
             );
```

Comment: Hello, hopefully, this is not too late, but I'm looking into optimization and I'm wondering what is the logic behind this ? It looks if a row with the information we are looking for (in this case ``Class`` and ``Industrial``) exists for given ID and if they do, return all rows associated with that ID right ?

Comment: @luisarcher . . . Yes, that is the idea.